# How to read specific n_rows and n_columns from parquet file?

Tags: python, parquet

How can I read first row and specific columns 1,3,5 from the parquet file?
Currently I use `pd.read_parquet(filename,columns=['first_col','third_col','fifth_col'])` to read only the columns that I want but I don't know how to read only first row while reading those specific column from parquet file.

Answer (score 0):

With [`pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.iter_batches`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.html#pyarrow.parquet.ParquetFile.iter_batches) approach:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

parquet_f = pq.ParquetFile('your_filename.parquet')
row = next(parquet_f.iter_batches(batch_size=1, columns=['first_col','third_col','fifth_col'])).to_pandas()
```

---

Changing `batch_size` param allows you to yield the needed number of records.

---

Comment: I got AttributeError: "ParquetFile' object has no attribute 'iter_batches' error Roman.

Comment: @Susan, ensure that you have recent versions of `pyarrow` and `pandas` installed